# Solving a symbolic matrix equation with SymPy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, solver

I am using sympy to solve a matrix equation. For example

```
A = sym.MatrixSymbol('A', 5, 5)
s = sym.MatrixSymbol('s', 5, 1)
z = sym.MatrixSymbol('z', 5, 1)

eq = A * s - z

solution = sym.solve(eq, s)
```

I am expecting "solution" to contain A^{-1}z, as s = A^{-1}z is a solution to As - z = 0. However, solution contains an empty list when I run this code. Any advice on how to get the result I am looking for here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could have had an even simpler example that does not give a solution:

```py
import sympy as sym
s = sym.MatrixSymbol('s', 5, 1)
z = sym.MatrixSymbol('z', 5, 1)

eq = s - z

solution = sym.solve(eq, s)
```

I think there is very limited support for solving equations with MatrixSymbols. I couldn't find anything to do with it in the documentation. Instead, either ignore the fact that it is a matrix and treat it as a non-commutative Symbol OR define all your elements in the matrix as individual Symbols:

```py
A, s, z = sym.symbols("A s z", commutative=False)
eq = A * s - z
solution = sym.solve(eq, s)
```

```py
A = sym.Matrix(5, 5, sym.symbols("a0:25"))
s = sym.Matrix(5, 1, sym.symbols("s0:5"))
z = sym.Matrix(5, 1, sym.symbols("z0:5"))
eq = A * s - z
solution = sym.solve(eq, s)
```

The first solution seems to be the consensus on [GitHub](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7379). The latter needs to find the inverse of a 5x5 matrix by first principles which takes exceedingly long. Chances are you'll have to wait a few minutes for it to solve this basic equation. It is, however, fairly useful for 3x3 matrices where one might want to see individual elements of `s`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using non-commutative symbols and I can't take transposes of arbitrary symbols. Is there a way to take the transpose using non-commutative symbols?

Comment: I found [this article](https://zulko.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/symbolic-matrix-differentiation-with-sympy/) that might solve these problems. It's strange that something like this isn't in SymPy after 6 years.